# How to bake crushed peppermint into cake?

Tags: baking, cake, cupcakes

I'm still fairly new to baking and I'm making cupcakes for a Christmas party on Thursday and I couldn't seem to find a recipe online for the the kind I want to make, which is a peppermint cupcake.  Instead of sprinkling it on top of the icing, I wanted to mix the peppermint into the cake batter and bake it.

Basically, should I play it safe and use peppermint extract/sprinkle the crushed peppermint on top? or is it possible to bake the candy into the cake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can bake crushed peppermint candy into cake. If you're talking about candy cane type candy, you can just crush it and add it to the batter, you wouldn't have to make changes to the recipe at all except the addition. It won't affect the way the cake bakes. The very edges of crushed candy might meld into the cake a bit, but I would expect that effect to actually be pretty nice. The sharp edges would be just a bit softened. Whether it maintains it's own character would mostly depend upon the size of the pieces. Powder might dissolve, but distinct pieces (like .3-.5 centimeter or so) would stay distinct.

Comment: Agreed, it's clearly possible. I think the main possible issue (though I'm not sure if the OP is concerned with this) is whether you'd expect to retain some texture or if it's going to melt/dissolve in like confetti cake.

Comment: Some variety would be nice.  So long as the cupcakes don't end up too chunky or too melted inside, I think the outcome will be wonderful. I was wondering: how much crushed peppermint should I add to each cupcake (regular sized, 6-8cm)?

Comment: That's pretty subjective, I'd probably go with 1.5 tablespoons or so, especially if I used a sieve so that there wasn't any powder, just distinct pieces.

Comment: ... but if you sieve it, save the powder to sprinkle on after frosting them.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the crushed peppermint to the cake batter, you run the risk of the pieces sinking to the bottom of the cake (from personal experience). I had luck with sprinkling the crushed pieces over the top of the batter once in the pans. The pieces sunk into the batter, but not all settling onto the bottom. Were dispersed wonderfully into each bite :)